# RtcLocalView.SurfaceView not working on Android Release APK (ReactNative)

Tags: react-native, agora.io

I have an issues with Agora functions not working when I build a release APK for Android.

Android ver: 10
ReactNative ver: 0.62.2
react-native-agora: 3.0.1-rc.3

I already upgraded everything to the latest versions and made sure that all permissions are added in my AndroidManifest.xml.

Also have permission checks fired when app is opened.

RtcLocalView and RtcRemoteView are not displaying, my users are not able to Join agora channel.
These seems to work on debug mode.

Have anyone experience this issue?
I'm not sure what codes you would like to look att, so if you guys want me to provide anything, let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Agora just released [3.0.1-rc.4](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-agora) with a few [fixes](https://github.com/AgoraIO-Community/react-native-agora/blob/HEAD/CHANGELOG.md).
I tried building a sample app and everything seems to work correctly on a build apk. You should try updating to the latest version, that should fix the issue.